# Can't save child objects with OneToMany Relationship in Springboot/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am building an order tracking system in `Spring Boot`, using `Hibernate annotations` and `Repositories`. I have an `Order` class, which can have a list of `OrderItems`. These map to a `ORDER` and `ORDER_ITEMS` table respectively. The code I have representing the two is below.

**Order.java**

```
package net.township.order;


import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {
    public Order() {
}

public Order(long merchantId, String firstDeliveryName, String 
lastDeliveryName, String deliveryAddress, String status, Date createDate, 
Date updateDate) {
    this.merchantId = merchantId;
    this.lastDeliveryName = lastDeliveryName;
    this.firstDeliveryName = firstDeliveryName;
    this.deliveryAddress = deliveryAddress;
    this.status = status;
    this.createDate = createDate;
    this.updateDate = updateDate;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "order_id", unique = true)
private long orderId;

@Column(name = "merchant_id")
private long merchantId;

@Column(name = "first_delivery_name")
private String firstDeliveryName;

@Column(name = "last_delivery_name")
private String lastDeliveryName;

@Column(name = "delivery_address")
private String deliveryAddress;

@Column
private String status;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = { 
CascadeType.ALL,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE })
private List<OrderItem> orderItems;

@Column(name = "create_date")
private Date createDate;


@Column(name = "update_date")
private Date updateDate;


public void setOrderId(long orderId) {
    this.orderId = orderId;
}

public long getMerchantId() {
    return merchantId;
}

public void setMerchantId(long merchantId) {
    this.merchantId = merchantId;
}

public List<OrderItem> getOrderItems() {
    return orderItems;
}

public void setOrderItems(List<OrderItem> orderItems) {
    this.orderItems = orderItems;
}


public String getLastDeliveryName() {
    return lastDeliveryName;
}

public void setLastDeliveryName(String lastDeliveryName) {
    this.lastDeliveryName = lastDeliveryName;
}

public Date getUpdateDate() {
    return updateDate;
}

public void setUpdateDate(Date updateDate) {
    this.updateDate = updateDate;
}

public Long getOrderId() {
    return orderId;
}

public void setOrderId(Long orderId) {
    this.orderId = orderId;
}

public String getFirstDeliveryName() {
    return firstDeliveryName;
}

public void setFirstDeliveryName(String firstDeliveryName) {
    this.firstDeliveryName = firstDeliveryName;
}

public String getDeliveryAddress() {
    return deliveryAddress;
}

public void setDeliveryAddress(String deliveryAddress) {
    this.deliveryAddress = deliveryAddress;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Date getCreateDate() {
    return createDate;
}

public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
    this.createDate = createDate;
}
}
```

**OrderItem.java**

```
package net.township.order;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "order_items")
public class OrderItem {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Order getOrder() {
    return order;
}

public void setOrder(Order order) {
    this.order = order;
}

@Column
private String name;

@Column
private String description;

@Column
private Long quantity;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn (name="ORDER_ID")
@JsonBackReference
@Cascade(value={org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
private Order order;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Long getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(Long quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
}
```

When I `POST` a new `Order` from my front-end, it is mapped to an `Order` object correctly. All `OrderItems` that were provided in the `JSON` are present in the object as a `List` as well. However, after I save it to the database using my `OrderRepository`'s save method (it's just a `CrudRepository`), my database contains a new `Order` object with the correct fields, but nothing is ever created in `ORDER_ITEMS`.

I've poked around the documentation for both `Hibernate` and JPA `OneToMany` annotations, and I don't see where I'm going wrong here. I'll also add that I'm doing no manual schema creation, letting `SpringBoot` handle setting up everything in `H2` for me.

Comment: Minor comment: `CascadeType.ALL`, `CascadeType.PERSIST` , `CascadeType.MERGE` is somehow redundant: `CascadeType.ALL` already includes the other types.

Comment: You can't cascade in both directions, you have to pick one direction as the master, and one direction as the slave (usually Hibernate will throw an error if you don't do that). By default, the Collection is always the slave. This is to avoid incoherent schemas which Hibernate can't resolve.

Comment: do you set attribute `order` for OrderItems before save?

Comment: can you share your service?

Comment: @Nikolay I don't manually set any values for these objects. My controller receives them as application/json and converts them. I then use a CrudRepository to perform the save. The code from my service is literally just
    userRepository.save(order)

Comment: Are you sure that data from front-end is correct? Debug `order` before saving and share it.

Comment: @Nikolay yep, the JSON was properly formatted, and my service logged that the Order object it received via the controller contained all fields I expected to be populated. I have posted an answer with the code that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ultimately worked for me.

Order.java

```
package net.township.order;


import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "orders")
    public class Order {
    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(long merchantId, String firstDeliveryName, String lastDeliveryName, String deliveryAddress, String status, Date createDate, Date updateDate) {
        this.merchantId = merchantId;
        this.lastDeliveryName = lastDeliveryName;
        this.firstDeliveryName = firstDeliveryName;
        this.deliveryAddress = deliveryAddress;
        this.status = status;
        this.createDate = createDate;
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "order_id", unique = true)
    private long orderId;

    @Column(name = "merchant_id")
    private long merchantId;

    @Column(name = "first_delivery_name")
    private String firstDeliveryName;

    @Column(name = "last_delivery_name")
    private String lastDeliveryName;

    @Column(name = "delivery_address")
    private String deliveryAddress;

    @Column
    private String status;


    @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "order_id")
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems;

    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Date createDate;


    @Column(name = "update_date")
    private Date updateDate;


    public void setOrderId(long orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public long getMerchantId() {
        return merchantId;
    }

    public void setMerchantId(long merchantId) {
        this.merchantId = merchantId;
    }

    public List<OrderItem> getOrderItems() {
        return orderItems;
    }

    public void setOrderItems(List<OrderItem> orderItems) {
        this.orderItems = orderItems;
    }


    public String getLastDeliveryName() {
        return lastDeliveryName;
    }

    public void setLastDeliveryName(String lastDeliveryName) {
        this.lastDeliveryName = lastDeliveryName;
    }

    public Date getUpdateDate() {
        return updateDate;
    }

    public void setUpdateDate(Date updateDate) {
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
    }

    public Long getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(Long orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public String getFirstDeliveryName() {
        return firstDeliveryName;
    }

    public void setFirstDeliveryName(String firstDeliveryName) {
        this.firstDeliveryName = firstDeliveryName;
    }

    public String getDeliveryAddress() {
        return deliveryAddress;
    }

    public void setDeliveryAddress(String deliveryAddress) {
        this.deliveryAddress = deliveryAddress;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }
    }
```

OrderItem.java

```
package net.township.order;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "order_items")
public class OrderItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private Long orderId;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @Column
    private Long quantity;



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Long getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Long quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Add `CascadeType.ALL` to your mapping.